# Probability with multiple uniform distributions

Tags: probability, uniform-distribution

Question:

Two sources output a number at equal rates.  The output from source A is uniformly distributed between 100 and 199, and the output from source B is uniformly distributed between 50 and 249.  If the number 125 is output, what is the probability that it came from source A?

I'm assuming I need to look at the pdf of each source, but I'm not sure if I have to form some sort of joint probability function.  Any help/hints are appreciated.

Comment: Nope, this is discrete. You just need bayes rule

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Hint:*

You need to find $P(\text{The number came from source } A|\text{The number is } 125)$. 
You have $P(\text{The number is }x|\text{The number came from source } A)$ and $P(\text{The number is }x|\text{The number came from source } B)$.

Also I think "Two sources output a number at equal rates." may mean $P(\text{The number came from source } B)=P(\text{The number came from source } A)$.

Now use Bayes rule.

Comment: This makes sense, also I agree with your last comment.  In that case P(A)=P(B)=1/2, correct?  This helped me better understand, thanks!

Comment: The final answer should be 2/3 as well I believe.

Comment: @JoeD I think it is right :-)

Answer (score 0):

$P\left(A\mid X=125\right)=\dfrac{P\left(A\wedge X=125\right)}{P\left(X=125\right)}=\dfrac{P\left(X=125\mid A\right)P\left(A\right)}{P\left(X=125\mid A\right)P\left(A\right)+P\left(X=125\mid B\right)P\left(B\right)}=...$

Comment: Thank you, I used this as a check after the help above!